# :reject_if blank on nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I have a nested form where each post has many locations. The problem is, if a user creates a location and then leaves it blank it populates my table with blank data.

I thought this would do it in my `post.rb` model:

```
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :locations, :allow_destroy => true, :reject_if => proc { |attributes| attributes['name'].blank? }
```

But they are still slipping through and being saved when blank. Any idea why?

EDIT: Here is the hash as requested in the comments:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓","authenticity_token"=>"r74iCzC4tJgVI6FiCEH7XzfiTmaqKihF5JSs7Ow3MSI=", "post"=>{"title"=>"This is a test blog post fo
r stack overflow", "body"=>"This is a test blog post for stack overflow", "tag_list"=>"", "locations_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"name"=>"London", "long
itude"=>"-0.1276831", "latitude"=>"51.5073346"}, "1354382846976"=>{"name"=>"Paris", "longitude"=>"2.3522219", "latitude"=>"48.856614"}, "1354382
849464"=>{"name"=>"", "longitude"=>"", "latitude"=>""}, "1354382850624"=>{"name"=>"", "longitude"=>"", "latitude"=>""}}}, "_wysihtml5_mode"=>"1"
, "name"=>"", "legname"=>"Paris", "longitude"=>"2.3522219", "latitude"=>"48.856614", "commit"=>"Submit"}
```

Comment: could you post the params hash that you use to create the Post ? my guess is that it is malformed to start with. Did you know that using accepts_nested_attributes also automatically save the association whenever you save the post, running validations ? see: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AutosaveAssociation.html

Comment: Thanks! Yea, I'm guessing it's because i'm doing some pretty funky stuff in my create function which changes the attributes so they can be checked for uniqueness. I think it's back to the drawing board with those then. I've posted the hash just in case anything comes to you!

Comment: your location_attributes are weird. It shouldn't be a hash, it should be an array of hashes (see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html). Don't know if this causes the trouble

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show your code for you location model, but it sounds like you need to add validation such as:

```
validates :name, :longitude, :latitude, presence: true
```

Without these the location record could be built with blank values for these three fields. All you are probably getting populated is the post_id.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by both separating out the attributes into an array and removing blanks and then removing any blank rows from the table.

```
locations = []
locations = locations.delete_if { |elem| elem.flatten.empty? }
```

`after_save { |location| location.destroy if location.name.blank? }`

Thanks for the suggestions!